# Reassigning class instance variable reference to local variable reference

Tags: java

```
private Node firstNode = null;

public void test() {
    int item = 0;
    Node lastNode;
    lastNode = firstNode;
    newNode = new Node(item);
    firstNode = newNode;
//Expected lastNode to now point to newNode. However, I get a nullpointer Exception because lastNode is still null
```

Why is lastNode still null? Shouldn't lastNode now reference newNode since firstNode was reassigned to reference newNode?

Comment: lastNode = firstNode; line no 3
you could also place 
newNode = new Node(item);
    firstNode = newNode;
before line no 3 to avoid it

Comment: Why do you think `lastNode` would be non-null? You first assign the value of `firstNode`, which is `null`, and then you never assign a new value to `lastNode`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is not a valid object instance, so there is no memory allocated for it. It is simply a value that indicates that the object reference is not currently referring to an object. From JVM Specifications: The Java Virtual Machine specification does not mandate a concrete value encoding null.

So, on the line:

```
lastNode = firstNode;
```

you are not assigning `lastNode` a reference to `firstNode` object. And when you change `firstNode` `lastNode` remains null.

Comment: Only answer that addresses the fact that null is not an object or a type and therefore cannot be reassigned.

Answer (score -1):

owing to `private Node firstNode = null;`，and you assign "NullPointer" to lastNode。
so... lastNode is alway null except firstNode has `non-null` reference.